# Http cache for symfony

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, caching, http-headers, cache-control

I want to follow [Google's directive in terms of cache headers for images](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#invalidating-and-updating-cached-responses), scripts and styles.

After reading symfony's [documentation about http cache](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html), I decided to install [FOSHttpCacheBundle](http://foshttpcachebundle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). The I set up rules for path like `^/Resources/` or `^/css/`. I then fail to see it the proper headers for my images using Chrome's console.

Alternatively, I have read that, since my server is handling the resource, this is not Symfony that deals with this matter (yet I read in the doc that Symfony Proxy was good for shared-hosting servers, which is what I have).

So should I just add lines to my `.htaccess` as explained [in here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/how-do-i-set-expiration-headers-for-css-js-and-images), or am I simply misusing FOSHttpCacheBundle? (Or both.)

Comment: Does FOSHttpCacheBundle cache generated HTML and also other files (images, CSS, etc.)?

Comment: You mean improper configuration of the [Symfony HttpCache](http://foshttpcache.readthedocs.org/en/stable/symfony-cache-configuration.html)?

Comment: No, I'm wondering if FOSHttpCacheBundle only cache web pages and ignore scripts and styles.

Comment: Do you know I can check that? But my best attempt at caching css/js with FOSHCB my localhost could not retrieve the js/css files (returned a 500 in the console).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static files (including javascript files, CSS stylesheets, images, fonts...) are served directly by the web server. As the PHP module is not even loaded for such files, you must configure the server to set proper HTTP headers. You can do it using a `.htaccess` file if you use Apache but doing it directly in `httpd.conf`/`apache2.conf`/vhost conf (depending of your configuration) will be better from a performance point of view.

If you also want want to set HTTP cache headers for dynamic content (HTML generated by Symfony...), then you must use FosHttpCache or any other method provided by Symfonny such as [the `@Cache` annotation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/cache.html).